# iControl REST Remote Authentication BIG-IP v11.5.1 and LDAP

Tags: f5

I am using F5 IControl 11.5.1,i have integrated ldap and working fine but i need to access F5 using icontrol rest service.

is there any rest end point available in 11.5.1?
what are parameters and how to pass for ldap?

Answer (score 3):

iControlRest is available in 11.5.1. It was introduced in 11.4 as an early access feature and fully implemented in 11.5. The documentation for iControlRest can be found [here](https://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/iControlREST.HomePage.ashx). You can find the endpoints and examples for how to use them there. [Here's another link](https://devcentral.f5.com/d/icontrol-rest-user-guide-version-1150) to the PDF of the user manual for the 11.5.0 version.

The format for using iControlRest is `https://BIGIP/mgmt/tm/ltm/pool`. The endpoints use Basic authentication so you'll need to make sure to that the basic Authorization header. Also, you'll need to use an account that has admin permissions to the box.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to bypass LDAP/TACACS or remote authentication as of this time in any version. I recently opened a case for the same issue. The service account you use must exist in LDAP or you have to use the "admin" account.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, F5 came up with a concept of Role Based Access Control (RBAC), — create a local user a/c but here you can be able to just add Username and Role. No password entry is available. Make sure you use Username that is not listed in the remote role groups on the remote authentication server (Active Directory - ldap).